# Heap instrumentation failed with exit status 1 [Android]

Tags: android

I have been using heap analytics for a while now and as of a few days ago I am unable to build run my project without it failing unless I set `ext.heap = ["enabled": false]`.  I have not made any changes to my gradle files.  I have also tried updating to the latest version of heap for android (0.8.3) but no luck.  The only thing I can think of is that updating android studio to 3.3.2 may have caused this issue. Here is the console output:

```
Caused by: com.heapanalytics.android.gradle.HeapGradleException: Heap instrumentation failed with exit status 1
at com.heapanalytics.android.gradle.InstrumentationCommand.run(InstrumentationCommand.java:71)
at com.heapanalytics.android.gradle.HeapPlugin$1.lambda$execute$1(HeapPlugin.java:553)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue with Heap analytics or have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Can you please tell if you were able to address this issue?

Comment: @ashwinmahajan I have not.. I keep it off when I am deploying from Android Studio to a device.  However I have it enabled for my production builds and they generate without an issue.  Creating APKs doesn't seem to be affected so if you need to have it enabled for your debug builds that is a workaround for now.

Comment: Fortunately, for me, it just started working, I have no idea why. Anyways, thank you  for letting me know.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I am not able to make it work. I tried changing the heap size and did a invalidate and restart but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue, apparently Heap (current latest version `1.2.0`) is incompatible with the new gradle plugin version.

I fixed by downgrading from:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0"
```

to

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1"
```